# Grabbing per minute stock data from a large time range Python

Tags: python, pandas, finance, yahoo-finance

So I'm trying to grab per minute stock data over a one year time gap and I know the Google Finance API doesn't work anymore so I did some digging around I found some code from a old github thread that could find the range within 5 days from yahoo finance data; however, it does not do anymore than that even when I put a keyword like '1Y' which defaults to 1 day. Here is the code below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import arrow
import datetime
import os

def get_quote_data(symbol='AAPL', data_range='5d', data_interval='1m'):
    res = requests.get('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/{symbol}?range={data_range}&interval={data_interval}'.format(**locals()))
    data = res.json()
    body = data['chart']['result'][0]    
    dt = datetime.datetime
    dt = pd.Series(map(lambda x: arrow.get(x).datetime.replace(tzinfo=None), body['timestamp']), name='Datetime')
    df = pd.DataFrame(body['indicators']['quote'][0], index=dt)
    dg = pd.DataFrame(body['timestamp'])    
    df = df.loc[:, ('open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume')]
    df.dropna(inplace=True)     #removing NaN rows
    df.columns = ['OPEN', 'HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME']    #Renaming columns in pandas

    return df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body['meta']['validRanges']` tells you:

```
['1d', '5d', '1mo', '3mo', '6mo', '1y', '2y', '5y', '10y', 'ytd', 'max']
```

You are requesting `1Y` instead of `1y`.  This difference is important.

By the way you can load the timestamps much more easily like this:

```
pd.to_datetime(body['timestamp'], unit='s')
```

Comment: I tried '1y' and I got the following error:
  File "grab_data.py", line 78, in <module>
    data = get_quote_data('AAPL', '1y', '1m')
  File "grab_data.py", line 26, in get_quote_data
    body = data['chart']['result'][0]    
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Don't be helpless.  Don't expect to copy-paste code, copy-paste the errors one by one into Stack Overflow, then repeat.  Investigate.  What is the error message the API gave you in that case?  Hint: you can use `res.raise_for_status()` to automatically throw an exception when an error occurs.

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "grab_data.py", line 80, in <module>
    data = get_quote_data('AAPL', '1y', '1m')
  File "grab_data.py", line 25, in get_quote_data
    print(res.raise_for_status())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 939, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 422 Client Error: Unprocessable Entity for url: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/AAPL?range=1y&interval=1m

Comment: Oh I see, I can only do per minute requests for up to 7 days.. damn thats a bummer.

Answer (score 0):

```
print('stock ticker: {0}'.format(get_quote_data(symbol='AAPL', data_range='1d', data_interval='1m')))
```

works